# differentiate between operator and operand

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm, metrics

I have a few questions regarding operators and operands. Take a look at these code samples:

```
Random r = new Random();
foreach(List<Point3d> individual in sG)
{
    index1 = r.Next(0, individual.Count);
    distance = actual.DistanceTo(next);
}
```

I know that these are the operators:

```
foreach() -- () -- ; -- = -- . -- , -- new
```

And I know that these are operands:

```
r -- individual -- sG -- index1 -- distance -- actual -- next -- 0
```

However what is with:

```
List<Point3d> -- in -- Next -- individual.Count -- DistanceTo -- Random
```

I'm guessing that `List<Point3d>` should be an operand and `DistanceTo` an operator but not sure at all.

For your information, I'm trying to calculate the Halstead Metrics for my genetic algorithm.

Here are some links where I got the information. Maybe it will be useful for others in search like myself. [Measurement of Halstead Metrics](http://www.verifysoft.com/en_halstead_metrics.html) ; [Halstead metrics: Example](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aserebre/2IS55/2010-2011/10.pdf) ; [Halstead Metrics: Example in German](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/se2/metriken.pdf)

Comment: `foreach` is a *statement*, not an operator. The semicolon is not an operator, either. Not everything in a programming language is either an operand or an operator. More specifically, objects handed to a function/method are generally referred to as parameters, not operands.

Comment: @s.m. In the case of a function call, they are technically operands, but nobody uses that term, everyone uses the term "parameters" for the function invocation operator.

Comment: FWIW - in C# developers seldom speak of *operands.* I'll go so far as to say that I've never heard anyone refer to an operand. [Here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/) to details about many C# *operators*. You may find that the term means something different in this context. So the terms may have some meaning in the way you're using them, but not to C# developers in general. Using them differently may lead to confusion.

Comment: @s.m.  I actually know that but for the Halstead Metrics you only have to sort them into operators and operands. There are a few links where they list operators and operands. Considering the links 'for' is an operator but 'foreach' was not listed. However I thought when for is an operator so should be foreach.

Comment: @ScottHannen Looking at some of the operators from your own link you'll see usage of the term "operand".  It's not a term that comes up *all* that often, but it's a perfectly sensible term, and the question uses the term appropriately.

Comment: I didn't know this Halstead Metrics thing even existed. From a cursory glance, it very much looks like some metric for management to masturbate over. Predicting the number of bugs (and the Time To Code!) based on sums of the count of operators and operands divided by some arbitrary quantity (3000? 18?) and multiplied by the log of something is delusional at best. Software is made by humans, and this kind of metrics is downright laughable. Sorry for the OT, I just can't bear stupid metrics.

Comment: @s.m. Well it's ok if you can't bear them however you can measure complexity of algorithms with them. With Halstead you can calculate the difficulty to understand an algorithm or the volume of it. Another example: with McCabe Metric you can calculate the structure complexity of your code. With these metrics you can analyze whether your software/ algorithm/ whatever is good enough or not. Another example: there is the Big O Notation as well. Well actually it's not fun for me either but I want to do it for my report and for a good grade.

Comment: Oh sure, I understand, especially if it's a matter of grades! Big O notation is in a quite different league, though: it tells you the *actual* complexity of an algorithm based on the size of the input, and it doesn't depend on, for instance, the skill level of the developers. The same does not hold true for Halstead. While the former is a function of the input size, the latter is a function of many things, factors that are both human and technical (such as the choice of which implementation language is being used, which might lead to those numbers changing).

Answer (score 0):

**List<>** It's a [Generic Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) collection. What it stand for is that it's a list of Point3d which is another class.

**in**: it's a reserved word which works with the foreach statement. It means iterate for each element IN sG (which is a variable with lots of List and put the current element in the "individual" variable.

.DistanceTo, .Next, .Count, .Random, etc are **methods** and **properties** of each class.

I recomend you to read something about [Object Oriented Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming) before continue with that algorigthm...

Answer (score 0):

`in` - is operator
`Random`,`List<Point3d>` - are Types
`.Next()`,`.DistanceTo()` - are functions
`individual.Count` - is property

More about these all you can read [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/language-specification)